# Is Julia's discipline related to her escape in S5E10?

Tags: the-magicians

According to the books, in alternate timelines, Julia's discipline is Meta-Composition, which means she kinda has a foot in all disciplines. She has talent in all things magic, which presumably is still true in timeline 40. She has psychic abilities well before season 5 in the show, demonstrating 
empathic powers (possibly due to her godhood?)

In season 5, episode 11,

> Julia escapes from Castle Whitespire's dungeon by travelling out. She's capable of this because she's carrying Penny 23's baby, and it's explained that mothers of psychic children often sometimes gain their abilities in times of crisis.

This doesn't seem like a full explanation.

> Travelling accurately

is incredibly difficult to do, even if you're naturally born into it. And Julia does it on her first try.

Is Julia capable of the incredibly impressive feat of

> travelling accurately

because her discipline is Meta-Composition?